# Mobile menu not clickable in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

The mobile view menu on a client's site is not selectable/clickable within IE9. On other browsers (firefox, chrome) the menu is 100% working.

In IE9

[image]

Other browers:

[image]

I'm taking over this site from an outsourced agency and haven't gotten to grips with a majority of the code base.

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: post some codes or fiddle it.

Comment: How do you trigger the menu? Could you please give us a code sample? Have you checked the developer console?

Comment: Looks just like my first css3 website did when I tested it on ie9 willing to bet its related to lack of css3 support.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, but if you use `bootstrap-theme.css`

There is a line of code somewhere around line 194 and 221

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
```

I read in other website that resolved the issue. I can't guarantee though

[Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10257)